# How to modify "Summary View" in SharePoint list web part?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I'm using the Announcements list on a team site and I'm displaying the list on a page using the out of the box list web part.  I like the fact that the Summary View trims the body of each list item, but I would like to display an additional column in the summary view.  Is there a way to do that without having to use SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 3):

You can show additional information by modifying the web part, clicking "Edit the current view" and adding your additional column. This will show up underneath your body text.
If that is not where you want it.. you'll need SharePoint Designer.